# Custom data structure (element + weight)

Tags: java, data-structures, heap

Which data structure should I use to keep elements ordered by a given weight? I need to add elements in a collection where each element generate a specific weight, but this weight is not contained (neither calculated) inside the element itself; it is calculated by someone else outside of the element. Moreover, the weight does not need to be stored (but could be if needed), it is only an insert parameter to put the element at the right position.

My specific use case is to sort music tracks. I have a list of tracks and a list of rules to apply on each tracks. I iterate through each track, then the list of rules generate a "score" given the current track. I would like to add the track into a "collection" given the generated score, so I can pick the first track with the highest score.

I can't see which data structure to use in Java. Do I have to implement a new one myself? My best guess is a kind of heap data structure, but I can't figure out which one specifically.

EDIT:
The weight is only calculated once at the beginning. I can't provide a "comparator" since it will compare Tracks, and I can't calculate their score on a "compareTo method".
The algorithm could look like:

```
 public Track determineNext() {
     MyStructure<Track> trackScores;
        for (Track track : tracks) {
            int score = 0;

            for (Rule rule : rules) {
                score += rule.applyScoreOn(track);
            }

            trackScores.add(track, score);
        }
     return trackScores.first();
 }
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)?

Comment: How often is the "weight" calculated? Can it change? If so, when does it get recalculated?

Comment: If the weight will not change, SortedSet: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html with a comparator is possibly what you need, but it depends how else the data might be accessed.

Comment: Can you use the calculated score *for* the `compareTo()` method? This looks *exactly* like the kind of thing `PriorityQueue` was implemented for.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is exactly what you need:

> The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used.

In this case, the *natural ordering* would be by score. Easy.

As to your point:

> I can't provide a "comparator" since it will compare Tracks, and I can't calculate their score on a "compareTo method".

The key here is that you don't use the `compareTo()` method to calculate the score. It's the other way around. You use the score in the implementation of `compareTo()`.

---

You have a few ways to implement this:

1. Make `Track implements Comparable<Track>`, and implement `compareTo(Track t)` compare the scores you scored, so higher score --> "larger" object. The `PriorityQueue` will take care of the rest.
2. Implement a `Comparator<Track>` that does basically the same thing as `compareTo()` does for option 1.

Option 2 is better if you might sort using different criteria later in the program, as you don't commit yourself to having `Track`s only sort by score.

Ideally, for both options you would store the score inside `Track`, as the score will only need to be calculated once; however, you'll have to make sure that this score is set before inserting into the `PriorityQueue`. That shouldn't be an issue though.

Alternatively, can calculate the score on the fly inside the comparing methods, if you know the score won't change over time; this can get somewhat expensive over time, though, if lots of comparisons have to be made. I wouldn't recommend this if you know the score won't change.

---

Alternatively, if `Track` objects are ignorant about their scores (which makes sense), you can use a `Map` with `Track`s as the key and scores as the value to associate a `Track` with a score:

```
HashMap<Track, Integer> scoreMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Track track : tracks) { // Copied from question, slightly altered
    int score = 0;

    for (Rule rule : rules) {
        score += rule.applyScoreOn(track);
    }

    scoreMap.put(track, Integer.valueOf(score));
```

Now you can use a Comparator that pulls scores from this map

```
public class TrackComparator implements Comparator<Track> {
    private final Map<Track, Integer> scores;

    public TrackComparator(Map<Track, Integer> scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Track t1, Track t2) {
        // Check to see if tracks are in map if you didn't pre-fill map
        // Get scores, compare, return
    }
}
```

There are a few caveats, though:

- `Map`s generally require you to define additional methods (`hashCode()` in addition to `equals()` for `HashMap`, and some form of comparator for `TreeMap`)
- The keys for a map should not be mutable, although for `Track` objects I can't really see that being an issue
- You get another collection to eat up memory. However, if your scores are in the range [-128, 127], that shouldn't be too much of an issue. It is possible to pass VM flags to expand this range, too. I wouldn't worry too much about memory consumption unless you either have an insane number of tracks or several different maps floating around.
- Just changing the map's value externally does not reorder the priority queue. You will have to remove() and add() the Object whose "score" changed for it to move to its new position in the queue.

I'm not too certain that the `Map` solution is the *best* solution, but I think far from the worst, and should be pretty good on its own.

A possible change to help with memory issues is to put the `Map` inside the `Comparator`, and have the comparator itself calculate scores if needed and add them to the map if the track isn't already there. This depends on whether you care about some scores being "frozen" later than others. This might affect performance adversely, but that's a big guess.

Comment: I have a class that knows the collection of tracks and the list of rules. Ideally, I would prefer that Track knows nothing about score.

Also, I know I may have a very large collection of tracks and a pre-defined list of rules (let's say 15). I would like to calculate the score only once per computation of the algorithm (ideally) and I'm afraid that PriorityQueue do it more than once on the same element (maybe not?).

I didn't want to mislead the information, but the score might give a different result each time the algorithm is computed, but will be calculated once at the beginning.

Comment: @MiniW Hmmm... If `Track` shouldn't know anything about score, perhaps use a `Map` to associate a `Track` with an `Integer`/`Long` representing score?

Comment: Also, whether the score is calculated multiple times per element depends on how you choose to implement the comparing methods. `PriorityQueue` will almost certainly call a comparing method on an element multiple times, but if you cache a value that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: That was one of my thoughts, but I was wondering if there were an existing data structure designed for this kind of thing.

Comment: @MiniW Updated answer for way to do this without `Track`s knowing about score.

Comment: @MiniW I don't know if there is a data structure that does *exactly* what you need, but I think `PriorityQueue` with a `Comparator` is the closest you can get. What you want sounds a bit specialized for a specific data structure to exist, although it could be just me not knowing of it. This is the best I can come up with at the moment.

Comment: @MiniW (Hopefully) final update with a bit more code.